# Different Microwaves same Mug

Tags: thermodynamics

So my old microwave (which worked fine) heated a cup of coffee in about a minute to a good temperature. I would pull it out and could hold the mug handle with no issue.

That microwave recently broke, and I replaced it was a slightly smaller microwave (both in wattage and in cubic feet). Now I need to heat my coffee for about 1 minute and 20 seconds to get the coffee a good temperature, however I can no longer hold the mug handle as it gets very hot!

Can someone explain why my mug is now getting hot, where it didn't in the old microwave.

Comment: How many Watts was your old microwave? How many Watts is the new one? They aren't all the same.

Comment: The longer time in the oven allowed for more heat to be conducted from the liquid to the handle.

Comment: @BobD The handle is constructed specifically to stay relatively cold while the cup is holding boiling hot liquid. Since you can in a normally tempered room hold the cup with hot liquid for a basically unlimited amount of time on its handle, I doubt that the 20 more seconds time for heat conduction from the liquid into the handle in the new device can really do the trick here.

Answer (score 3):

The distribution of microwave energy inside an oven is often uneven, with hot and cold spots inside the oven volume. This is why they put turntables inside them- to move the food around relative to the hot and cold spots, so the food cooks evenly. Do both the ovens have turntables?

Answer (score 2):

Now I obviously can‘t tell you what exactly is going on, since I have almost no information about the 2 instruments you used. However 2 ideas that come to my mind are:

Hypothesis 1) The new device uses a slightly different frequency, which does get a bit stronger absorbed by your cup or a bit less strong by the water in the cup, then was the case for the old one. Perhaps you can take a look on what frequencies your devices run and see how much they differ.

Hypothesis 2) During heating inside a microwave oven there will actually be standing waves created. These do have resonance maxima at some points and minima at others, which is why they usually spin your food around while heating. (Fun fact: You can use this to measure the speed of light by heating cheese in a microwave oven with known frequency). Maybe your cup is just placed unluckily with a minimum on the water or a maximum on the handle, you might want to experiment a bit with the geometry inside your microwave oven.

Those were thoughts about why the handle gets hotter at similar coffee temperature. As for the different time it takes to get the coffee to a similar temperature, the slightly lower power level of your new machine seems to be the obvious explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> I replaced it was a slightly smaller microwave (both in wattage and in cubic feet).

Lower wattage rating corresponds to a reduced level of heating capability.  It will take longer to heat something to the same temperature as a higher rated microwave.

The volume of the microwave has very little impact on this, AFAIK.

To put this in perspective, the instructions on the sides of tins of soup I heat (obviously not in the tin !) almost all give different times for different wattage ratings.  A difference of a minute between 800W and 1000W would be ballpark.  All packed foods will typically have a statement to adjust the time in a microwave depending on the rating of the microwave.

So nothing unusual is happening.

> however I can no longer hold the mug handle as it gets very hot!

This is likely just a result of the longer times and the different rates the materials of the mug and the coffee absorb microwaves, radiate heat and conduct heat.  Again nothing unusual here, IMO.